# django orm relations - join three tables at diffrent fields

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

in my django model i have 3 model like :

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)

class DailyData(models.Model):
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
```

i want to join DailyData and Company on field instrument . and join this to Industry on field industry .

multiplie tables outer join on instrument and industry fields

Answer (score 0):

To Join table in django, you need to have relationship between the fields, the relationship could either be foreign_Key, OneToOne, OnetoMany, ManyToOne or ManytoMany.
Look at [select_related and prefetch_related](https://medium.com/better-programming/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d) for better understanding.